# Why regular polygons with a even numbers of sides have always a center of simmetry?

Tags: geometry

My questions is how to prove the statement:

"All regular polygon with a even number of sides have a center of simmetry", What is the demonstration of this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the precise meaning of *center of symmetry*?

Comment: As part of writing out the definition of "center of symmetry," it would be helpful to write what it means for a figure to have such a center. Your textbook or instructor may have written this differently than others would, so it's best if we can start with the definitions you were given rather than trying to use someone else's. (And who knows, maybe while you are writing these definitions into the question you will see an answer yourself.)

Comment: @DavidK He is asking for a strict proof of the following statement: All regular polygons with an even number of sides have a center of symmetry $O$. A center of symmetry is a point $O$ such that for each point $M$ of the polygon there is a different point of the polygon $M'$ such that points $O,M,M'$ are collinear and $OM=OM'$.

Comment: Exactly Oldboy, thanks for the definition.

Comment: What's a "center or symmetry".  Strikes me as obvious as all lines and angles are congruent there that the half polygon from vertex 1, 2,3....,n+1 in the  clockwise direction is congruent to the half polygon from 1, 2n-1, 2n-1, ....,n+1$ in the counterclockwise direction as all the corresponding parts are equal. Okay a very easy statement that angle bisectors of angle 1 and angle n are the same line but that's easy.

Answer (score 2):

Strict proof would go like this:

Suppose that you have a regular polygon $P$ with $2n$ sides: $A_1A_2...A_nA_{n+1}...A_{2n}$. According to the definition of a regular polygon, all sides have equal lengths and all angles between consecutive sides must be equal.

First you have to prove that bisectors of all polygon angles pass through the same point. Consider, for example bisectors of angles $\angle A_1$ and $\angle A_2$. They intersect at some point $O$. Angles $\angle OA_1A_2$ and $\angle OA_2A_1$ are equal (exactly one half of angle between consecutive sides) so triangle $\triangle OA_1A_2$ is isosceles and $OA_1=OA_2$. In exactly the same way you can show that $OA_2=OA_3$, ... $OA_{2n-1}=OA_{2n}$, $OA_{2n}=OA_1$.

So there is a point O such that all lengths $OA_i$ ($i$=1,...,$2n$) are equal and that point is the center of circumscribed circle. You can also easily prove that triangles $\triangle OA_iA_{i+1}$ and $\triangle OA_jA_{j+1}$ are congruent for any $i,j$ (because $OA_i=OA_j$, $OA_{i+1}=OA_{j+1}$, $A_iA_{i+1}=A_jA_{j+1}$).

Because of that all angles $\angle A_iOA_{i+1}$ are equal. Denote that angle with $\alpha$. Obviously $\alpha=2\pi/(2n)=\pi/n$

Triangles $\triangle OA_1A_2$ and $\triangle OA_2A_3$ are congruent so there has to be an isometric transformation that transforms the first triangle into the second one. Isometry with one fixed point $O$ is a rotation. So:

$$R_{O,\alpha}(\triangle OA_1A_2)=\triangle OA_2A_3$$

$$R_{O,\alpha}(\triangle OA_2A_3)=\triangle OA_3A_4$$

$$...$$

$$R_{O,\alpha}(\triangle OA_{n}A_{n+1})=\triangle OA_{n+1}A_{n+2}$$

Or:

$$R_{0,\alpha}(R_{0,\alpha}(...R_{0,\alpha}(\triangle OA_1A_2)...))=\triangle OA_{n+1}A_{n+2}$$

$$R_{0,n\alpha}(\triangle OA_1A_2)=\triangle OA_{n+1}A_{n+2}$$

$$R_{0,\pi}(\triangle OA_1A_2)=\triangle OA_{n+1}A_{n+2}$$

In other words, if you have a point $M\in P$ that belongs to triangle $\triangle OA_1A_2$, rotation around point $O$ for $180^\circ$ transforms that point into some point $M'$ that belongs to triangle $\triangle OA_{n+1}A_{n+2}$ i.e. to some point $M'\in P$.

Rotation around a fixed point $O$ for $\pi=180^\circ$ is actually a central symmetry with $O$ being a center of symmetry.

So every regular polygon with $2n$ sides has a center of symmetry which is also a center of a circumscribed circle.